# ¿Como redefinir un constructor en php?

Tags: php

mi pregunta es sencilla, ¿Como hago para redefinir el constructor de la clase padre, con diferente comportamiento?

Lo que quiero hacer es heredar de la Clase Excepcion de php (que su constructor imprime por pantalla la excepcion), y redefinir ese constructor para que no muestre nada.

```
<?php 

    class Excepcion404 extends Exception{

        public function __construct() {
            //Este metodo muestra una vista 
            Vista::crear(GENERAL_BUNDLE."views/index.php");

        }
    }
```

Cuando hago:

```
throw new Excepcion404();
```

El resultado que obtengo es que me muestra la vista, pero abajo de todo esto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Excepcion404 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\controladorFrontal\ruta.php:64 
Stack trace: 
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\controladorFrontal\ruta.php(18): Ruta->buscarEnElArray('/dafasdwdaw') 
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\controladorFrontal\ruta.php(8): Ruta->submit() 
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\rutas\rutas.php(7): Ruta->controladores(Array) 
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\controladorFrontal\core.php(29): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\index.php(6): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
    #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Neomix\controladorFrontal\ruta.php on line 64
```

Quisiera que solo me muestre la vista y que no imprima ese error horrible.

**AGREGADO:**

Estoy construyendo un framework propio, cuando capturo la URI lo que hago es llamar a una función que busca en un array, si esa URI existe en mi web, en caso de encontrarla me devuelve el controlador que voy a utilizar y el metodo:

```
...código...
$respuesta = ruta.buscarEnElArray($urlCapturada);
...código...
```

y mi función hace lo siguiente:

```
public function buscarEnElArray($rutaABuscar){
            foreach ($this->_controladores as $url => $controladorYmetodo) {
                if($url == $rutaABuscar){
                    return $controladorYmetodo;
                }
            }

            throw new Excepcion404();

        }
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué tienes puesto cuando capturas la excepción? ¿Puedes mostrar la parte del código donde la misma ocurre? Por otra parte, creo que al constructor le faltan parámetros, por ejemplo, el mensaje que debería mostrar en caso de excepciones. Si observas el ejemplo del Manual de PHP no deberías tener problemas al construir tu clase de manejo de excepciones personalizada: http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.extending.php Saludos.

Comment: Ya agregue el código

Comment: Como te decía, el constructor de tu clase personal de excepciones debe recibir parámetros: `class Excepcion404 extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0) { ...`  Cuando levantas la excepción le mandas sea un mensaje o un código para que la clase sepa el mensaje que debe mostrar:  `throw new Excepcion404("Datos para el constructor",1);` Mira el ejemplo del Manual de PHP, te puse el enlace más arriba. Si quieres puedes manejar la clase en base a códigos personalizados y según el código muestras un mensaje. Tal y como funciona cualquier sistema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tiene sentido crear una excepción que no arroja una excepción. Va contra el concepto de excepción.

La `Excepcion404` es una buena idea, pero no es ahí donde tienes que mostrar la vista.

El código para mostrar la vista lo tienes que poner en la sección `catch` de un `try`.